# Run a WinForms project on Mac OS

Tags: c#, macos, winforms

I have a standard WinForms project I wrote in Visual Studio C# that I would like to be able to run on my Apple (non-mobile) devices.
After some light research, I saw that a program called Mono supposedly offers this capability, but after playing with it for a while, I can't seem to get it to work and the instructions offered for it are quite awful.
Is there another option for porting a WinForms project to run on Mac OS, or a good, detailed set of instructions for Mono available elsewhere than mono-project.com?

Comment: Detailing what you have actually tried would go a long way towards getting answers here. As is we would just be guessing

Comment: You probably won't be thrilled with Mono's WinForms implementation on Mac even if you get your app to run.  It was incomplete and was abandoned years ago.  I had a very small WinForms app that I was able to run, but it was a very basic app and there were still glitches.

Comment: Does that mean there is essentially no good way to port a WinForms to a Mac environment?